# Create GIT branch but not for all files in repository

Tags: git, branch

I've recently started with git and github and I've been struggling with one thing now: can I create a branch where only certain files are tracked?

**Example**
My *master* branch has two files (1.py and 2.py). Now I'd like to add functionality to 2.py so I want to create a branch for only that file, which would mean I do track 2.py but I do not track 1.py. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR version: you don't.

I think you're misunderstanding how git works. In git there are commits and references to commits. Branches (and tags) are just a reference to a commit (with rules about updating the reference when you create a new commit). It is all just a DAG (directed acyclic graph) of commits.

There is no sense of just branching part of a commit (this would be nonsensical).

If you want to remove a file, you'll need to create a new commit in which that file is no longer included.

If you only want to change a single file in a branch (which is just a reference to a commit)  then only change that file. Just leave all the other files unchanged. Should you merge back to master only the net changes between the two branches are applied.

(The underlying git model is very different to "traditional"  version control systems, trying to apply those models to git will only make using git harder. If you are using git then use git as git, not as something else.)

Comment: Thanks Richard, clarifies all of it :)